# ¿Como puedo enviar datos de un componente a otro, cuando están en módulos diferentes en Angular 4?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular4

## ¿Como puedo enviar datos de un componente a otro, cuando están en módulos diferentes en Angular 4?

Saludos comunidad, no e podido resolver mi siguiente problema, tengo una data que esta en un componente dentro de un modulo y quiero pasar esa información a otro componente que esta en otro modulo diferente. Yo se que con input y output puedo pasar datos entre componentes padres-hijos pero como puedo hacerlo si estan en diferentes modulos?

probe con esto pero no me a funcionado:

**local.service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()

export class LocalService{
    private addItemToBasketSource = new Subject<string>();
    addItemToBasket$ = this.addItemToBasketSource.asObservable();

    addItemToBasket(item: any) {
        this.addItemToBasketSource.next(item);
    }
}
```

**loginform.component** (en este componente inserto el dato)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {LocalService} from '../../shared/services/local.service';

constructor( private localService : LocalService ) {}

onReturn(){
    this.localService.addItemToBasket("RUFJSJS");
}
```

**establecimientos.component** (aqui quiero leer esos datos)

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {Observable} from "rxjs";
    import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';
    import { LocalService } from '../../shared/services/local.service';

    export class EstablecimientosComponent implements OnInit {
      subscription: Subscription;
      public showCard:boolean = false;  
      numeroFormulario: Observable<string>;
      public inscrito:Inscrito;

      constructor(private localService : LocalService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.subscription = this.localService.addItemToBasket$.subscribe(
          response => {
            console.log(response);
          }
        )
      }
}
```

Comment: Usa localStorage, por ejemplo

Comment: No puedo usarlo por que son datos muy sensibles del cliente

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que lo que has probado no ha funcionado? ¿No se escribe nada en la consola?

Comment: los datos se guardan pero cuando me subscribo no me trae nada

Comment: la función next() es de el observador, no del observable. Si simplemente es guardar un dato de acceso inmediato, quizá deberías no usar observables y simplemente devolver el objeto, evitando "sobre-ingeniería"

Comment: tienes algún ejemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías simplificar tu service, quitando el uso de Rx.
Como en principio sólo se creará una instancia de este service, que se inyectará en los distintos componentes cuando la necesitan, puedes simplemente guardar en un atributo los objetos (o el objeto, si sólo se quiere guardar uno, en el ejemplo asumo varios y se guardan en un array).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LocalService{

    private stored: any[] = [];


    addItemToBasket(item: any) {
        this.stored=item;
    }

    getItemsFromBasket() : any[] {
        return this.stored;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Pablo!!