# ¿Cómo pasar parametros entre pantallas?

Tags: angular, rxjs

¿Cómo puedo pasar datos entre pantallas mediante el uso de servicio?

Me gustaria saber cómo pasar objetos completos de una pantalla a otra en angular.

He creado un servicio que me permite emitir data:

import { EventEmitter, Injectable, Output } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavigateScreenPoService {

  @Output() navigateScreen : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }
    
}
```

Posterior a ello tengo una función en el componente principal llamada enviarInformacion() la cual se encarga de emitir la información y al mismo tiempo navegar a otra pantalla cuando he dado click.

enviarInformacion() : void {
this.navService.navigateScreen.emit({
data: "Mensaje de prueba"
})

```
this.router.navigateByUrl("/dashboard/add-evidence-po");
```

}

y por ultimo tengo otro componente independiente donde al inicializarlo hago la suscripción al servicio y este recibe la información de manera correcta, mas sin embargo tengo problemas para renderizar la información en la vista.

```
this.myEventSubscription = this.navService.navigateScreen.subscribe(data => {
     this.data = data;   
     console.log(this.data);
});
```

Mas sin embargo cuando trato de renderizar la información de esta no renderiza, he probado con async y await, pero no ha funcionado de manera correcta.

Les agradeceria que me ayudarán a explicarme a que se debe esto y cual es solución mas optima.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esto responde tu pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835123/how-do-i-pass-data-to-angular-routed-components

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como puedo enviar datos de un componente a otro, cuando están en módulos diferentes en Angular 4?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119382/como-puedo-enviar-datos-de-un-componente-a-otro-cuando-est%c3%a1n-en-m%c3%b3dulos-difere)

Comment: Prueba con BehaviorSubject en tu servicio. Output no está pensado para usarlo como lo usas, aunque también sea un observable. Salu2